# datastore not working when we declare intent route to a page containing datastore in DialogFlow CX

Tags: dialogflow-es, datastore, vertex

We confirm the following bug, which was impossible to correct on our side after some days of tests, with clear limitation when using datastore to get data content.
As soon as we declare an intent route to a specific page (other than the start page) with the involved page containing a data store,  on DialogFlow CX, the data store is not called. There is nothing !
The problem is only with a intent route configuration pointing to a page. In case there is no intent route pointing to the page containing the data store, there is no problem.
Again, as soon as we configure intent route pointing to a page containing a datastore, then it is not possible to use datastore.  ;
May you please advice and fix this major bug

We tried to use a page containing a datastore with no intent route , and the data store of the page works well
As soon as we declare intent route the datastore does not work
In a normal mode the datastore is used to transfert information